# I had a problem with Appium and couldn't fix it

Tags: testing, appium, appium-android

> ''' An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
> command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error:
> 'Command 'D:\program\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s
> f8cb3e08 install -g
> E:\appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk'
> exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install
> E:\appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\apks\settings_apk-debug.apk:
> Security exception: You need the
> android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use
> the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag
> java.lang.SecurityException: You need the
> android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use
> the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag at
> com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:596)
> at
> com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(Package';
> Code: '1' '''

I've turned on administrator mode
Usb debugging is also enabled
And other environments are already configured
This is my parameter

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "7.0",
  "deviceName": "f8cb3e08",
  "appPackage": "com.tencent.qqlive",
  "appActivity": "ona.activity.SplashHomeActivity",
  "noReset": "true",
  "autoGrantPermissions": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use automation name as capability.

```
"automationName":"UiAutomator2"
```

You can use `appium` instead `UiAutomator2` as default.